# Uncaught Error: Expected to find a document already present for removed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

When I try to log into app, the error I get in client console (chrome dev tools) is this:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected to find a document already present for removed mongo.js?69942a86515ec397dfd8cbb0a151a0eefdd9560d:253
```

and the login is halted: the loading gif from the accounts-google package shows and the loading never ends.

I however get no errors in server console. Unfortunately, the error gives me little understanding as to where to even start debugging my app from.

I have gone through the portion where the error is thrown in the mongo.js file, but I don't get what's going on there from it either.

Since I do not have any idea where I am going wrong, this is the link to the [project repository](https://github.com/seanmavley/preach).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @sapna Nope. The project was discontinued though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you was use fast-render package and doing 2 subscriptions for the same publication as explined [here](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render/issues/12#issuecomment-32462112)

Hope this help someone.